# String processing in Maxima

Tags: string, maxima

I am new to Maxima.

I've read the manual and I couldn't find a function to identify whether a certain variable is present in a string or not.

Note: I am trying to create a function that allows me to mimic the Maxima function augcoefmatrix().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you're trying to do, but string operations on stringified expressions is almost certainly the wrong way to go about it. What, exactly, is your goal here?

Comment: I am to create a function that is similar to augcoefmatrix() of maxima. A function where it would accept equations and will output an augmented coefficient matrix, same as augcoefmatrix() would do.

Comment: @Enzo OK. Maybe you are looking for `freeof`. I have posted an answer to your other question.